# htaccess only redirects and won't rewrites

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have setup .htaccess for rewriting URLs but it only redirects. How can I make it rewrite rather than redirect?

What I want to happen?
User goes to example.com/foo and sees content from example.com/bar. Browser should keep example.com/foo in URL bar.

What happens?
user goes to example.com/foo and is redirected to example.com/bar. Browser URL updated.

My htaccess file:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#THIS REDIRECTS NON HTTPS TO HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#THIS SHOULD REWRITE BUT INSTEAD IT REDIRECTS. WHY???
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^foo/$ https://example.com/bar[L,QSA]

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
```

This is my apache .conf file:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
Require all granted
AllowOverride All 
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#THIS SHOULD REWRITE BUT INSTEAD IT REDIRECTS. WHY???
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^foo/$ https://example.com/bar [L,QSA]
```

It redirects because you're using full absolute URL (one starts with `http://` or `https://`) in target. In order to avoid redirect use a relative URI in target as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^foo/$ /bar [L,NC]
```

Make sure to clear browser cache or use a new browser to test this change.

Comment: I changed as you suggested but example.com/foo. Although redirect is not happening it is not getting the content from bar. Any ideas?

Comment: The rewrite condition is not being met by my URL when I don't include the full URL in the second part of the rewrite Rule.

Comment: Turns out issue with htaccess and codeigniter so new question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55170064/htaccess-rewrite-url-does-not-work-with-codeigniter-code